# Using perl system grep

Tags: perl, shell, mod-perl

Have the below perl grep `regex` and it's working properly.

```
  my  @cont = grep {/,\s*511747450\s*,\s*CAN2\s*$/} @fileContents;
```

I want to convert it to unix system `grep` and I tried the same regex using `system` command in the below way and it's not working.

```
  my $cmd="grep ,\s*5117474501\s*,\s*CAN2\s*\$ " . $dirPath . "/" .$fileName;
  my $exitStatus =system($cmd);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\`, `*` and `$` are special to the shell. Some more escaping is in order.

```
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );

my $pat = ',\\s*5117474501\\s*,\\s*CAN2\\s*$';

my $cmd = shell_quote('grep', '--', $pat, "$dirPath/$fileName");
my $exitStatus = system($cmd);
```

Or you can simply avoid the shell by using the multi-arg form of `system`.

```
my $pat = ',\\s*5117474501\\s*,\\s*CAN2\\s*$';

my @cmd = ('grep', '--', $pat, "$dirPath/$fileName");
my $exitStatus = system({ $cmd[0] } @cmd);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info.  Is the System command takes one argument or two arguments system({ $cmd[0] } @cmd); ? Could you pls explain me what is passed in the argument. Is it a array or the first element of the array?

Comment: Three are three forms. `system $CMD`, `system $PROG, @ARGS`, `system { $PROG } $PROG, @ARGS`

Comment: thanks.  does the example follows system { $PROG } $PROG, @ARGS ?   system({ $cmd[0] } @cmd) cant understand what is passed in the argument.  Is it the first element of the array or array itself because i am unable to find a comma in the argument.

Comment: @Arav, yup. Neither, the resulting list of scalars is passed.

Answer (score 3):

grep doesn't work with `\s` in bash in some versions.

Try `[:space:]` instead of `\s`.

The behaviour of grep varies between different versions.